# How to get jar lib files of jongo?

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

Follow at [jongo](http://jongo.org/) a java library on top of MongoDB allow Query in Java as in Mongo shell.
Example:

SHELL

`db.friends.find({"age": {$gt: 18}});`

JAVA DRIVER

`friends.find(new BasicDBObject("age",new BasicDBObject("$gt", 18)));`

JONGO

`friends.find("{age: {$gt: 18}}").as(Friend.class);`

But I can't find anything to download these jar lib files.
Who could share this file with me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project is hosted on the Sonatype OSS library, so you could search for it here https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~jongo

A quick search for the latest jar turned up https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=org.jongo&a=jongo&v=0.2&e=jar

Comment: Thank @David Welch for  your help and for Jongo, i love it.

Comment: My pleasure. As @yves amsellem said, using the Maven dependency would make life easier. If you're using an IDE that has maven support, just create a new Maven project and add the dependency to the pom.xml file. It'll make life a lot easier :)

Answer (score 0):

As said by David Welch, you can download Jongo directly on Sonatype.
You can also use its maven dependency, it will ease the version upgrades to come:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jongo</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>
</dependency>
```